# OpenDaylight beginner tutorial for Sodium

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I've already looked up the opendaylight documentation and searched the internet for a simple beginner tutorial in writing a opendaylight application. I have not found a tutorial that is current enough to use it with **opendaylight sodium**. I would liked to write a simple learning switch app, because opendaylight doesn't have the L2switch app anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could still check out the l2switch project and try to bring it up
to date with the current ODL core projects and try to build it. I don't
know how difficult that would be, but I know it should be possible.

As for not having a good tutorial for developing an app, I'm guessing
you found [this](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html) and it was not current enough. I've never used it,
but if you have any specific problems in it, maybe we can find an
answer to those specifically?

Comment: Yeah, I already saw this tutorial but it's not very detailed, barebones at most. For instance the package structure of an opendaylight application is not explained e.g. the l2switch project structure is not structured in api, cli artifacts etc. I've already tried the l2switch project but there are over 30 different classes in 6 directories + new dependencies in pom files and osgi blueprint files. I think it's not the best project to begin with.